# Paypal subscribe button charged on the first day of every month

Tags: paypal, wordpress, paypal-subscriptions

I am new to programming and creating Paypal payment buttons in which i want to use subscribe button with my plan.

I have a service to sell monthly 2,500JPY and i want to charge it on the first day of every month.

and if customers buy the service in the middle of the month, i want to charge by the day.

For example, if they but it on April 5th, they pay 2,166JPY (2,500 divided by 30days, multiplied by 26 days) on April 5th. and they pay 2,500JPY on the first day of every month.

Any subsequent help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a non hosted clear text PayPal button this way it would allow you to dynamically modify the variables.  Then you would have to build in the logic into the code to correctly calculate the billing terms and amount, and then have those dynamically populate the variables in the subscription buttons.